# Como poner la primera letra del texto de un botón en minúscula

Tags: java, android-studio, botón

Tengo un botón que tiene de texto la letra `i`. Para esto coloco en `string.xml` la letra `i`, pero al ejecutar la aplicación me aparece la  letra en mayúscula (`I`) y quiero que sea en minúscula.

Ya intenté asignarle la letra desde el archivo [java](/questions/tagged/java) del layout y con el método `setText("I")`, pero me vuelve a poner mayúscula la letra y necesito que sea en minúscula.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Hola Jose, bienvenido. Recuerda pasar por el [Tour] y [ask]. Deberias añadir el codigo que has intentado para que podamos ayudarte sobre él. Además, has puesto en la pregunta `setText("I")` con la `i` mayuscula pero la quieres minuscula no ? Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir de una versión de Android, esto se muestra así por defecto. Para cambiar esto, tienes que editar el *tema* de tu aplicación. 
Para ello ve a tu archivo `themes.xml` que se encuentra en la carpeta `values` y crea tu propio estilo para los botones.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/miBoton</item>
</style>

<style name="miBoton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```